# The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. Flutter Issue

Tags: flutter, null, flutter-widget

```
  @override
  Widget? buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: AnimatedIcon(
        icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
        progress: transitionAnimation,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }
```

Null is causing the trouble

Pls solve this flutter issue as soon as possible

Comment: Add some code of `close` Function. That way someone can suggest what you should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because of the flutter null safety feature
try this,

```
onPressed: () {
                 close(context, '');
              },
```

pass the empty string, because of the flutter null safety you can not assign null values.